# Association in a custom validation method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I made the following class, but it didn't work correctly.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :validate_department_code, on: :create
  def validate_department_code
    if self.department_code.present?
      department = Department_code.find_by_name(self.department_code)
      user.build_participation(department: department)
    else
      self.errors.add(:department_code, :not_found)
    end
  end
end
```

After validation, the user is saved in DB, but the participation is not saved. So user.participation becomes nil.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `User.rb`, add an after_create on a condition.

It should look like:

`after_create :create_participation, if: :department_code.present?`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It solved the problem.

If possible, I want to know why my post code didn't work correctly.
Does anybody know?

Comment: `validate`should only be used for validation purposes. Note that in addition to the code I gave you, you could/should still use validation, such as: `validates :department_code, presence: true`

Comment: Hi @graboros, can you accept my answer if it solved your problem?